# Is it possible to bypass install UAC prompt without registry editing (Windows 10)

Tags: uac, window, windows-installer

My computer is controlled by an admin and, as such, I can't run app installer programs. I trust you can imagine how inconvenient this is for me. I have tried the RunAsInvoker command in PowerShell, but I get the return prompt "Registry editing has been disabled on this device". Is there another way to bypass the UAC prompt without using registry editing or the RunAsInvoker command?

(P.S. Regedit is blocked as well)

Comment: Even if you bypass UAC you still won't have permissions to do whatever your attempting to do

Comment: UAC just asks for proper credentials. You cannot install software because normal users cannot install software. Also this questions comes up a lot as well.

Comment: @John I already know why I'm not allowed to install software.

Comment: And @Ramhound I only want to run the, say, installer program for spotify.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because member is trying to bypass company / other security

Comment: @John understandable.

Comment: There exist solutions that do not contravene company policy.

Comment: @randominternetperson - If Spotify requires an Administrator to install it, then it's changing something, that requires elevated permissions.  If you are unable to provide those permissions it would fail even if you bypassed UAC.  You can disable UAC but bypassing UAC without first turning it off (requires you be an Administrator) would be very tough.

Comment: @harrymc a "solution" might not, but the act of a user installing software on a machine owned by an entity that does not wish the user to install software is contravening company policy and is, rightly, looked upon dimly here.

Comment: @music2myear: It's all a matter of semantics - if the post would have been phrased as "I need a utility for my job that is not installed on my computer but cannot install" your attitude might have been different. I prefer in such cases to give the poster the benefits of doubt and help him with his underlying problem rather than his stated problem.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install without administrator permissions that you don't have.

If you have any virtual machine product that is already installed on
the computer, you could create a virtual machine, which is basically
a computer where you are the only administrator.
*This way, you will not enter in conflict with your company's
security policy.*

Another solution to installing software products is to find a portable version
of these products that can work without installation.
The website
[PortableApps.com](https://portableapps.com/)
contains a list of such products.